# Vite manifest not found at: D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginGoogle\public\build/manifest.json

Tags: laravel

When I run `npm run dev`, I get an error:

```
PS D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginGoogle> npm run dev

> @ dev D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginGoogle
> vite

failed to load config from D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginGoogle\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'
Require stack:
- D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginGoogle\node_modules\vite\dist\node-cjs\publicUtils.cjs
- D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginGoogle\node_modules\vite\index.cjs
- D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginGoogle\vite.config.js
- D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginGoogle\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-934dbc7c.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `vite`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I am trying to run `composer require laravel/jetstream`, `php artisan jetstream:install livewire`, `npm install`, `npm run dev`

Comment: Please post the contents of your `vite.config.js` file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.